# Detect if user bought IAP Subscription

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, subscription

I create my first unity3d iAP with subscription purchase but I don't know how detect if user bought subscription, and how detect time bounds of the subscription

P.S. I used this [script](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use 'IAP Receipt Validation Obfuscator' and validate their receipt from Google Play or Apple Store, see the article below:

[Receipt Validation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPValidatingReceipts.html)

Comment: I opened this receipt and there is only for Google Play or I'm not understend, but my game is for iOS

Comment: There is code in the article pertaining to Apple as well. Look through all of the code. There's even a section at the bottom for parsing raw receipt data for Apple products.

Comment: How to determine the status of the subscription every time when I start the application, I saved Subscription Expiration Date in a PlayerPrefs but It is not safe...

Comment: You're right. PlayerPrefs is for storing simple things like game settings (volume level, gamepad sensitivity (if any), etc... Especially on mobile devices. I suggest you learn how to serialize your data into JSON, encrypt the .json file, and save it. It isn't hard to do and SO has tons of Q/A's on both serialization and encryption.